# Finding the Weighted Average in a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

The question is:For the previous Track, compute the weighted average (instead of the average) average yield by nation (yield is defined as dividend divided by price, and is reported as a percentage). The weighted average includes the quantity of shares as a weight. 
But I have no clue on how to find a weighted average.

I already have some code that was used to compute the average of the yield in percent. But I'm having trouble computing the weighted average. I talked to some classmates and they said they're trying to use the formula:  sum(x*w)/sum(w) where w is weight.
But I'm having trouble implementing this into my code

```
SELECT Nations.nationName, 
AVG(dividend/price) AS Yield
FROM Shares, Nations
WHERE Shares.nationID=Nations.ID
GROUP BY Nations.nationName;
```

In the end the weighted average should be computer but I just don't know how to implement that into the code. The material we're supposed to base this problem off of is no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed you correctly, you should consider:

```
SELECT 
    n.nationName, 
    SUM(s.quantity * s.dividend / s.price)/IIF(SUM(s.quantity) = 0, NULL, SUM(s.quantity)) AS weighted_yield
FROM Shares s
INNER JOIN Nations n ON s.nationID = n.ID
GROUP BY n.nationName;
```

Notes:

- always prefer explicit `JOIN`s over old-school implicit `JOIN`s
- also, using table aliases are a best practice, since they make the query shorter and easier to follow

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. But i wanted to know why you chose those three attributes (quantity, dividend, and price) to compute the weighted avg.

Comment: @AnaLiquid: dividend and price were already there in your query, and your question mentioned that you wanted to use the quantity as a weight, so...

Comment: @GMB MS Access doesn't support `nullif` unfortunately.

Comment: @LeeMac: ah yes, correct, I changed the query to use `IIF()` instead.